# Is it possible to list PHP files that have been included to make a final page?

Tags: php, include

Say there is a complex PHP script with a lot of dynamic inclusions of other PHP files. Is it possible to list all the files, that have been included up to a certain point of execution of a PHP script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, there exists [get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) function for that.

**Example:**

```
<?php
// This file is abc.php

include 'test1.php';
include_once 'test2.php';
require 'test3.php';
require_once 'test4.php';

$included_files = get_included_files();

foreach ($included_files as $filename) {
    echo "$filename\n";
}

?>
```

Result will be like:

```
abc.php
test1.php
test2.php
test3.php
test4.php
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php